# Database change history

Tags: django, django-models

I'm searching for a django package that would allow me to save history of my models, but only on updates. I found django-reversion, but after a quick look it doesn't seem to have such ability. Database triggers are also not an option, since my database structure is rather complicated, and writing them would be hard.

Comment: This can be useful: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/.

Comment: You can add answer with this link - if nobody gives me a better one, I will accept yours

Comment: Posting a link-only answer is a [poor practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice) generally. Since I've never used those tools by my own, I'll just leave it as a comment. Thank you, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem at some point.

My solution at that time was to define two models:

- **content**: which corresponds to an abstraction of *content* of the website. This model is what holds the current content of the website.
- **action**: which corresponds to an abstraction of *content change* on the website.

**content** has two pointers (OneToOneField) to actions: **first edit**, which is the action that created that particular content and **last edit**, the action that has the last modification made on the content.

**action** has one pointer (OneToOneField) to an actor, the user that made the action, and a pointer (ForeignField) to another action, the previous action on the particular content. It also has a TextField which saves content change. This can be for instance a diff-like text for databases, or simply a pickled dictionary.

In some sense this is equivalent to version control like git, where "action" is a commit on a specific content (and not on the whole project), and content is the source. Commits are linked via "previous commit", and save content change and user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/). It detects changes to your models and creates migration files that allow you to sync your database forward and backward.